# Implementing document view count in Solr

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, solr, solrnet

I have some articles in Solr and I show their details in my web application.

I've defined a SearchHandler in solrconfig.xml:

```
 <requestHandler name="/getbyid" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="wt">json</str>
      <str name="indent">true</str>
      <str name="qf">id</str>
      <str name="df">id</str>
      <str name="mm">100%</str>
      <str name="rows">1</str>
      <str name="fl">*,score</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

When user clicks on a document to see the detail, I extract data using this handler.

I've defined a field in schema.xml:

```
<field name="viewCount" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

When users clicks, I get the document using the handler, then I update the document with incremented `viewCount`.

Is there any built-in solution in Solr to implement the view count of a document?

If not, what is the best way to update the viewCount? (I should update viewCount and commit the document each time the users want to see it)

Comment: http://1opensourcelover.wordpress.com/2013/07/02/solr-external-file-fields/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update automatically during fetching data. 
The best solution I know, is to create batch xml commands and then POST the xml batch file to SOLR server in specific intervals.
Also, there are some new features in SOLR 4 like increment which could be useful in you scenario.